# Separate two XMLs from single file

Tags: java, xml, web-services, xml-parsing

I am getting response from Web service in XML form, It contains two different XML response in single XML returned by web service. 
**Example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transaction type>
...
...
</transaction type>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<verification_statement>
...
...
</verification_statement>
```

Which is the best way to separate this two xmls and put it in separate files? OR I mean to say How can i separate this two XMLs?
I have written web service client in JAVA.

**Code of getting response:**

```
 int status = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    httpConn.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.add(line);
            }
            reader.close();
            httpConn.disconnect();
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Server returned non-OK status: " + status);
        }

        return response;
```

Comment: I don't believe this is a correctly implemented webservice if it returns two XML documents concatenated together! Did you write it or is provided by a third-party?

Comment: provided by third-party

Comment: **That web service is *not* returning XML.**   Tell its owners to fix it or provide a proper specification for their interface that doesn't pretend but fail to be XML.   Otherwise, good luck guessing and writing custom text- (not XML-) level code for dealing with this idiosyncrasy and the inevitable additional problems that arise when standards are ignored.

Comment: @kjhughes agree with you.. let me check with provider.. meanwhile please share your views about what approach i may use in this case

Comment: I think in the meanwhile I'll simply hope that your vendor fixes their web service.

Comment: Service provider not ready to change there service.. :(  its actually doing 2 different operations on single request and result is return as output of this 2 operations

Answer (score 1):

Get your file in a String.

Use indexOf to search for the first and second < ?xml version="1.0",

Split in 2 parts, and process each xml String.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you will have some XML parsing mechanisms in your code base.

Simple suggestion - can't you just remove the xml header `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` and wrap the entire XML with a parent tag `<globalParentTag>`?

That way it will become a single big XML. Then, use your favorite XML parser and get the nodes. The first node will be first XML and the second node will be second XML.

If the XMLs are malformed, you'll anyhow cannot parse individually too. (You won't be able to parse both XMLs even if one is malformed - that's the flipside.).

Thanks.

Comment: and also both XMLs have references to different DTD files.

Comment: Yes, but parsers will not allow parsing with two xml declarations.  XML declaration is allowed only once and at the top. 

And since you have XML as a string, you can replace that with empty string so it doesn't mess with your parser. Eg: xmlString.replaceAll("<\\?xml [^>]+>", "");

Another point - as @adam has mentioned, it doesn't look correct to receive malformed XMLs as webservice response, even though its from a thirdparty library.

Comment: Two different DTD files? I didn't think about it. 
But if that's the case, can't you split the string merely by the XML declaration tag?

Comment: I got your point.. replacing with empty string i can think about this option as well